# representation of a complex number in polar from

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Write the following in polar form: $\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{1-\sqrt{3}i}$

$$\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{1-\sqrt{3}i}=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{1-\sqrt{3}i}\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{1+\sqrt{3}i}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{3}i)^2}{1^2+(\sqrt{3})^2}=\frac{1+2\sqrt{3}i-3}{4}=\frac{-2+2\sqrt{3}i}{4}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$$

$|z|=r=\sqrt{(-\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}}=1$

arg$z$=$tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot -2)=-\frac{\pi}{3}$

[acorrding to Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Bi*sqrt%283%29%2F1-i*sqrt%283%29%20in%20polar) $\theta=0$

Comment: Your function supplied to Wolfram arrived as $1 +\frac{\sqrt 3 i}1-\sqrt 3 i = 1$...

Comment: @abiessu my bad

Answer (score 1):

You forget the brackets in your wolfram formula, the correct one is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2Bi*sqrt%283%29%29%2F%281-i*sqrt%283%29%29+in+polar) and as you can see your result is correct.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i\sqrt{3}}=$$
$$\left|\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i\sqrt{3}}\right|e^{\arg\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i\sqrt{3}}\right)i}=$$
$$\frac{|1+i\sqrt{3}|}{|1-i\sqrt{3}|}e^{\left(\arg\left(1+i\sqrt{3}\right)-\arg\left(1-i\sqrt{3}\right)\right)i}=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{1^2+\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{1^2+\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^2}}e^{\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1}\right)--\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1}\right)\right)i}=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{4}}{\sqrt{4}}e^{\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1}\right)\right)i}=$$
$$\frac{2}{2}e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i}=$$
$$1\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i}=$$
$$e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i}$$

Comment: Can you please explain why you have multiple it by $e^{arg(...)}$ and why you took the absolute value of the expression? thanks

Comment: Because of Euler's identity: $|z|e^{\arg(z)i}$ with $z=a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Than $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$